# HAProxy Url pattern forwarding

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I am using HAProxy for load balancing a couple of web servers (HTTP mode). The web servers are strictly dynamic, ie, there isnt any static content, only web services.
The URLs of the type (analogous)

```
http://192.168.5.10:8080/small
http://192.168.5.10:8080/medium
http://192.168.5.10:8080/large
```

Now, when i configure HAProxy to forward the incoming requests to these 3 urls on couple of machines, I'm specifying the url_path using `acl` and `path_end`/`path_beg`, but upon placing the request I get `Not Found on Accelerator` error, which is making it harder to pin point the problem.

Below is the configuration that I'm using. Also, it is not logging any errors.

```
    global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      10000
        srvtimeout      10000

frontend http_proxy
        bind 192.168.5.9:8888
        acl is_small path_end -i small
        acl is_medium path_end -i medium
        acl is_large path_end -i large

        use_backend web_server_small if is_small
        use_backend web_server_medium if is_medium
        use_backend web_server_large if is_large

backend web_server_small
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpclose
        server  web_1 192.168.5.10:8080 check
        server  web_2 192.168.5.11:8080 check

backend web_server_medium
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpclose
        server  web_1 192.168.5.12:8080 check
        server  web_2 192.168.5.13:8080 check

backend web_server_large
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpclose
        server  web_1 192.168.5.14:8080 check
        server  web_2 192.168.5.15:8080 check
```

Is it possible to send the request from HAProxy to the web_server with the url_path?.

If HAProxy receives it as `http://192.168.5.2:80/small`, then send the request to the webserver as `http://192.168.5.10:8080/small`

Answer (score 5):

As your path is contained to the start of the URL why not use path_beg, the recommended use for path_end is for file name extensions.

```
        acl is_small path_beg -i /small
        acl is_medium path_beg -i /medium
        acl is_large path_beg -i /large
```

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, that doesnt seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked manually from the haproxy server whether you can connect to the backend machines on those URL's?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether the backend servers are up? Those are running and the corresponding URLs are functional as well.

Comment: You need to be on the haproxy server and test whether you can access the servers/URL's from there.

Comment: Well, that is the problem. If I host a server without any url_path, say `http://192.168.5.10:8080` and not `http://192.168.5.10:8080/small`, then it forwards the request. But I'm not able to forward it with the url_path. Atleast none of the configurations that I tried worked. Any idea how to include the url path with the forwarded request?

Answer (score 3):

The path of a HTTP request is **always** handed to the backend server, i.e.

```
GET /small HTTP/1.1
```

will be visible behind HAproxy as just that request. If you suspect that this somehow is truncated to

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

on the server behind HAproxy, you should check for this using

```
tcpdump -i any port 8080 -As1024 | grep GET
```

on that server and watch the inbound `GET` requests.

I'm going on a limb and assume that you expect HAproxy to **insert** something in the front of the URI, like

```
    server web_1 192.168.5.14:8080/my/path check
```

would turn a request for `/small` into a request for `/my/path/small`. This can be achieved by using the `reqrep` option, see the [documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt) for details.